# Python 3 Opening Binary into a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, binary

I have a binary file consisting only of hex numbers.
I want to open the file and create a list with each element of the list consisting
of 1 hexanumber of the file (e.g. 1 byte => AB for example would be 1 element).

I tried it with the "with open" and "readlines" commands and then split the lines into the element size i wanted but failed.
Also it somehow didn´t include a specific Hex number (in my case 0A).

my code is

```
with open(r"C:\Users\James\Desktop\Test1.bin","rb") as file:
    fileread = file.read
    linesread = file.readlines()
    splitted = linesread.split('\\')
print(splitted)
```

How do i go about?

Thanks for help

Comment: 1. Post [mcve]. 2. "but failed" How? 3. Have your tried binary mode (`'b'`)?

Comment: i included my code now i hope it helps